# Put short name of month in Gantt chart

Tags: pgfgantt

I am trying to make a Gantt chart using the `pgfgantt` package. I would like help with the following two issues:

1. I want the short month names starting from March 2023 up to 24 months instead of "1,2,3...,24".
2. I want to add the word "Month" in front of the list of months.

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid=true,
vgrid={*1{red, dotted}},
group left shift=0,
group right shift=0,
group peaks tip position=0,
group peaks height=.1,
y unit chart=0.8cm,
]{1}{24}
\gantttitle{2023}{9}
\gantttitle{2024}{12}
\gantttitle{2025}{3}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1}\\

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

And this is the corresponding output:

[image: Gantt_Test]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the small size, the months are overlapping. You can either change the dimensions of your Gantt chart or play with the values. This is how it looks currently (overlapping months is undesirable but necessary due to space) putting 9 months in 2023 and 3 months in 2025:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
    hgrid=true,
    time slot unit=month, % Added
    vgrid={*1{red, dotted}},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group peaks height=.1,
    y unit chart=0.8cm,
    time slot format=little-endian,]{01/04/2023}{31/03/2025}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
\gantttitle[%
    title label node/.append style={above left=19pt and 1pt}]{Month}{0}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Let me know what it is you seek or if this is okay.